# How to use push "route 10.0.0.0 255.255.255.0" on pfSense

Tags: networking, routing, lan, openvpn, pfsense

My OpenVPN server has a local IP address 10.21.1.4 (it's on the 10.21.1.0/24 subnet), and uses the 10.21.4.0/24 subnet for the tunnel. What route should I push to grant VPN clients access to the LAN (10.21.1.0/24)?

Should it be `push "route 10.21.1.0 255.255.255.0"` or `push "route 10.21.4.0 255.255.255.0"`?

**UPDATE 1**

Doing `push "route 10.21.1.0 255.255.255.0"` still doesn't allow my VPN clients to access the LAN. Momentarily, I added the following rules on the WAN and LAN interfaces:

```
Protocol: IPv4*
Source: *
Port: *
Destination: *
Port: *
Gateway: *
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to push the tunnel route, the client and server will both know about that (they figure that out in the setup).  The server will push things that aren't part of the tunnel -- it's other interfaces.

Also, pfSense will need explicit pass rules on the LAN and VPN interfaces for the VPN traffic.  So, assign you VPN server to an interface, it makes things easier, On pfSense, lets use the (assign) option under the interfaces menu to assign it to OPT1.  Then:

Firewall->Rules->OPT1 create a new rule (at the top is fine).

Action pass, Interface OPT1, IPv4, protocol any, source OPT1 net, destination any, description "let opt1 talk to anybody", save and apply

That rule says that all traffic that comes in from vpn clients is allowed to leave the firewall (to any destination)

Now we have to create a rule that says LAN clients are allowed to talk to VPN clients:

Firewall->Rules->LAN create a new rule (at the top is fine).

Action pass, Interface LAN, IPv4, protocol any, source LAN net, destination OPT1, description "let LAN talk to opt1", save and apply

note that we probably don't need this since the lan is very likely already allowed to talk to everybody but we're trying to make this easy right now.

Now, back to the OpenVPN options:

Say the server's lan interface is 10.20.30.40/24

```
push "route 10.20.30.40 255.255.255.0"
```

You may want enable netbios if you use Samba/Microsoft.  You probably want to add an in-office DNS.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Hi @quadruplebucky, thank you for your answer. The problem here is that if I use an  OpenVPN Client I get an IP from the tunnel subnet (in this case, 10.21.4.2), either on a cellphone or a Windows client. I understand I should have an IP from the LAN network (something in 10.21.1.0/24)

Comment: No, that's if you're using a TAP device (bridged).  You're using a TUN device.  It's actually advantageous in many ways (broadcast domain...etc) but that's another matter)

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't understand. Given that I'm using a TUN device, you're saying that I don't need to push any route?

Comment: It won't hurt anything to push the server's lan subnet if you want to grant clients access to that - a common smalll office type setup.   But I don't really know what you're trying to do, just guessing.  To make it clearer, say I want to get access to my desktop computer from home, from my laptop, and I don't know anything about anything, you could set me up with an openvpn client and remote desktop and I could probably work from home without much hassle.

Comment: That's exactly what I wan to do. In the LAN there are many services, such as HTTP, SMTP, etc., and I want VPN clients who are on the Internet to have access to them, as if they were there in the LAN :)

Comment: Do you have any suggestion on how I could achieve this?

Comment: I edited the answer.  I believe it's all you need to do.

Comment: Thank you very much. I already tried using the `push` part, but, could you provide an example on which rules I need. I currently have an allow on everything rule on the OpenVPN interface, but don't know which firewall rules to include in LAN.